# Monitoring Discharge Current

Tags: batteries, current, charger

I am currently working on a personal project and part of it involves battery charging and discharging. I intend to use Li-ion battery in my project. I've researched on various dedicated ICs especially in the BQ24xxx series. My concern is mainly in controlling battery discharge current from a fully charged battery. Are there any ICs capable of monitoring battery discharge current from batteries? Or is the discharge current from batteries dependent on the load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discharge current from a battery is DETERMINED by load, not just "dependent".

To control the discharge current you need to make a constant-current **load**, which is usually done with a powerful MOSFET, current-sensing resistor, and a feedback amplifier.

To "monitor" a discharge current, you need to insert a current monitor into discharge loop, usually a small-value shunt resistor connected to a specialized differential amplifier, like INA199 or ZXCT1109.

Comment: My question was more into controlling/setting rather than monitoring the discharge current. Thank you for answering both points of view i.e controlling & monitoring. I will try and research on Constant-current load as stated since I'm more inclined on how long my system can operate before battery charge "dies".

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but in case someone finds it later there is a nice document from Analog Devices coming as description & schematics on their battery test system named [CN-0352](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0352.pdf). It has a schematics and explanation of "electronic load" system, consisting of OpAmp, resistors and power MOSFETs which provides a configurable constant current load of 0-2A which are voltage controlled and designed especially for battery discharge purpose.